# Loopback 4 - Mongo and Elastic data synchronization

Tags: mongodb, typescript, elasticsearch, synchronization, loopback4

Is there an easy way to sync MongoDB data with Elastic if we are using a **Loopback 4** application? (In a NodeJS Express application we can easily do this using mongoosastic plugin.)

Currently in loopback a model is bound to one data source which is either a mongo or elastic. My ultimate goal is to write POST, PUT, DELETE methods in mongo (and replicate in elastic) and GET methods to use Elastic as datasource.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend to decouple the syncoronization part from the core routes of your application. You could leverage the MongoDB Change streams to listen for change and update your elasticsearch. This could be a simple app running on a totally different server which does the syncronization while you carry on serving your requests. This will make the overall process and architecture more durable and fault tolerant. You can read more about this on following link

[Mongodb to elasticsearch](https://medium.com/@montumodi/realtime-sync-from-mongodb-to-elasticsearch-using-change-streams-2559ad312011)